# R + ggplot2 - Aggregate Data by Intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a file where in each line i have a numeric value symbolizing an average duration:

```
12.3
5.4
6
...
```

There is some way in R to display the data in automatic or manual intervals/breaks (aggregate?). Something like this:

```
[0,1[ 0
[1, 6[ 1
[6, 20[ 2
...
```

Also, next i want to produce a plot in ggplot2 showing this data. Could i use these intervals as labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bin data with the `cut()` function in base R or use the Hmisc package and `cut2()`. There are several options on how to go about cutting and slicing your data, all of which are documented in `help(cut)` or `help(cut2)` respectively.

Once you have binned your data appropriately, plotting with ggplot becomes a trivial exercise:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Sample data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 1000, TRUE))
dat$cuts <- cut(dat$x, breaks = 5)

#Make bar chart
qplot(dat$cuts)
```